Why my spark structured streaming application doesn't stop when an assertion is failed?
When the app fails on the assertion, the app doesn't stop, and it seems like the stream is keep running. Actually, this is only an example, and I have multiple Spark streaming that run in parallel, but I think it doesn't matter because I called to spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination(3)
Any idea why?
object obj{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("SanityTest").getOrCreate()
    val eventHubConf = createEventHubConf()
    val df = sparkSession.readStream
      .format("eventhubs")
      .options(eventHubConf.toMap)
      .load()

    df.coalesce(1)
      .writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("parquet")
      .option("path", "output/filesink_output")


    spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination(3)

    val resultDf: DataFrame = sparkSession
      .read
      .parquet("output/filesink_output")

    assert(resultDf.count() == expectedNumOfEvent, "Assertion failed: Condition is not met")
 }
}

